# How to find the sum of df total capacity in bash cell

Tags: bash, linux-disk-free

I wrote a script to calculate the sum of the `df` total capacity in Linux' Bash shell. Is there a way to calculate it without creating a file?

```sh
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f /tmp/df_test.txt ]
then
    rm  tmp/df_test.txt
    echo "Remove files."
    else
    touch /tmp/df_test.txt
    echo "file creation."
        arr=(`df | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | sort -n | sed -e "1d"`)
        for i in ${arr[*]}
        do
            echo $i >>/tmp/df_test.txt 2>/dev/null
        done
fi
echo "ex) 1GB = 1000MB = 1000000KB"
echo "————————————————————————————————————"
cat /tmp/df_test.txt | awk '{sum+=$1; print$0} END {print"df total=KB)",sum} ' | sort -r | sed '2,$d'
echo "————————————————————————————————————"
rm /tmp/df_test.txt
```

I'd also like to make my code more concise but I'm out of ideas.

Comment: You can do `total=0; for i in ${arr[*]}; do let total += $i; done`

Comment: thank you.
Thanks to you, we can do more.

arr=`df -m | awk -F " " '{print $2}' | sed -e "1d"`;total=0;for i in ${arr[*]}; do let total+=$i; done;echo $total

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to get total usage in human readable units

```
df --total --human | awk 'END {print $2}'
```